# JavaScript selecting from list

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm stuck with a weird issue!

I have this code:

```
<script>
  window.PRICES = {
    'Gold' : { 10: 299, 20: 400, 100: 1745, },
    'Coins': { 10: 300, 40: 355, 1000: 30000, },
  };
</script>
<script>
function pick(i,n) {
  document.getElementById("Item").innerHTML = i+" "+n;
  document.getElementById("Price").innerHTML = (window.PRICES)[i][n];
}
</script>
```

The function `pick` is called by a select's `onchange` event:

```
<select name="Gold" onchange="pick(this.value,this.name)">
  <option value="10">10 Gold</option>
  <option value="20">20 Gold</option>
  <option value="100">100 Gold</option>
</select>
```

But when I change the value I get:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Gold' of undefined"

BUT `window.PRICES` isn't UNDEFINED!
Whats wrong?

PS: I'm able to call `pick('Gold','10')` using GC console!

Comment: Put a `console.log(i, n)` in your event handler and verify that the values are really what you want them to be.

Comment: wrong order of arguments, change to `pick(this.name, this.value)`

Comment: To not mix up such things give proper names to your arguments in the function, make it `function pick(name, value) {}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of the arguments of your `onchange` handler is switched. It should be `pick(this.name, this.value)`, since you are  accessing the `PRICES` object *first* by `name`, and only *then* by `value`, just like in your example `pick('Gold', '10')`.

Comment: @user1663047 : I would suggest you changing `function pick(i,n)` to `function pick(productType,amount)` too, so you don't have to remember/guess which is which.